# I am getting order_by fields in the form of a alphabetical order. I want to order_by by multiple values of field with django orm. List is like below:

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

`orderbyList = ['Day','Afternoon','Night']`

I am writing a query is like:

`modelclassinstance.objects.all().order_by(shift_name=*orderbyList)`

1. shift_name is name of the column and 'Day','Afternoon','Night' are
   values in it
2. my ultimate output should be like

   All day records first and then afternoon second and then night, not in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate a value for each of the values in `orderbyList` using [Conditional Expressions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) according to which the queryset will be ordered:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When


orderbyList = ['Day','Afternoon','Night']

order_case = Case(
    *[When(shift_name=value, then=Value(index)) for index, value in enumerate(orderbyList)],
    default=Value(len(orderbyList))
)

queryset = modelclassinstance.objects.annotate(order_case=order_case).order_by('order_case')
```

> **Note:** Although this solution will work you should instead look into having `shift_name` be in a **separate** model which would have
> some field to indicate it's ordering and order on that field. Your
> current model should simply have a foreign key to this model for
> `shift_name`. This would be better in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use conditional expressions (Case/When syntax): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

So something like:

```py
from django.db.models import Value, Case, When, IntegerField

modelclassinstance.objects.annotate(
    custom_order=Case(
        When(shift_name='Day', then=Value(1)),
        When(shift_name='Afternoon', then=Value(2)),
        When(shift_name='Night', then=Value(3)),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('custom_order')
```